# Is it possible to run setTimeout inside a iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, greasemonkey, video.js

I am trying to start an embedded videojs video using Greasemonkey. The video is running in a iframe and I managed to start the video in chrome with Tampermonkey but in Firefox the video starts loading and stops a sec later. I guess my following script starts too soon after reloading the page so I tried to delay the start with setTimeout but the code won't start. So my question is it possible to use setTimeout inside an iframe?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Autoplay
// @namespace   openload
// @include     https://openload.co/embed/*
// @version     1.0.0
// @run-at      document-idle
// ==/UserScript==

window.setTimeout(play, 5000);
function play()
{
console.log("Start");
document.querySelector('#videooverlay').click();
videojs.getPlayers()['olvideo'].player_.play();
console.log("End");
}
```

I use @include https://openload.co/embed/* to run the script inside the iframe otherwise I can't use the command .play().
If I open the iframeurl manually and use the commands over the FF console it works perfectly.

Comment: It's probable that in Firefox the video is played automatically after #videooverlay is clicked. Try commenting out the play() line.

Comment: I can't see what the actual problem is here. You present code that uses timeout, but title of your question asks whether you can use timeout... Does the timeout work for you? Do the `console.log` logs appear in the console?

Comment: Why don't you use `@include iframeurl` to execute the code in the correct window?

Comment: I have tried multiple ways with and without .click() and .play() but nothing changed

Comment: Tomáš Zato the problem is that the console.log logs not appear.
@w35I3y i added my greasemonkey header above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try something like this

```
window.addEventListener ("load", playerstart, false);

function playerstart () {

}
```

Comment: Explaining why this code works and giving more detail would probably be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want to add an "onload" event listener to the page loading in the iframe, and in the load function add the setTimeout.

I think the bigger issue to to figure out why it's not playing in Firefox. Is it an encoding issue? Do you have it in a source that FF can play? Miro Video Converter can help.

Comment: The source is hosted by openload.co and the player is embedded in a Website where I try to start the Video auto. after loading the Url. If I start the video manually it works normally so I don't think it's an encoding issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you tryed to start the script on the parent and inside the iframe? Then use setTimeout.

Comment: i thought i cant interact with the script inside the iframe ?